# Java Script: Array.length expression evaluate to boolean

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers, boolean

How to check array length, if I need the expression to evaluate to boolean value as a result? For example:

```js
var myArray = [];
if(!myArray.length){
  return;
}
```

Or:

```js
vr myArray = [];
if(myArray.length == 0){
  return;
}
```

Both of the examples work, however I’d like to understand what is the difference?

Comment: 0 is a [**falsy value**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), and as such, if a condition evaluates to 0, it is considered `false`. The preceding [`!` operator](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-logical-not-operator) (semantically "not") inverts the boolean to `true`.

Comment: array length is 0. but since 0 is false, condition is true in 1st. also null,"",undefined etc are false

Comment: It's important to understand the concept of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JavaScript. I think the linked resources will help...

Comment: There is no best solution - but I'll suggest you better.

Don't use == operator, in this case - length can be just number and you are comparing with a number so use ===

If you ask me, I would go with !array.length. And always use === instead of == (search for the book: JavaScript: The Good Parts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `!myArray.length` will return `true` in two cases:

- If `myArray.length===0` because `0` is a **[falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)**, so `!0` will return `true`.
- If `myArray.length` is `undefined`, in other words `myArray` is not an `array` so it doesn't have the `length` property, where `undefined` is **[falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)** too.

And the first one explains why both  `!myArray.length` and `myArray.length==0` are equivalent in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `length` function returns a Number and when you use Number as condition, `0` and `NaN` are evaluated as `false` (in other case is evaluated as `true`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an empty array, that is an array with `0` `length`,

single negation with `!` returns a misleading boolean.

```
arr = []

!arr.length // true - because `0` is `false`, `!` negates `false` to `true`

// double negate it for clear boolean
console.log(!!arr?.length, arr?.length); // false 0
```

Truthy example

```
arr = ['','','']

// array with values 
console.log(!!arr?.length, arr?.length); // true 3
```

Make sure to check if `.length` exists with optional chain `?`

```
if (!!arr?.length) console.log(!!arr?.length);
```

Now you can reliably use `.length` as a boolean to check for empty arrays.

Note: Double negation has caveats like ESLint's [no-extra-boolean-cast](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-extra-boolean-cast)